# How to find a Git branch which contain the specified commit hash

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have a Freestyle pipeline in Jenkins which is a declarative pipeline and sometimes it's getting triggered manually using the commit hash only as a parameter. I want to use this commit hash to find the exact branch. Jenkins is connected with Bitbucket.
I was using this command: `git for-each-ref   --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin --contains 5688e303418 | awk "/a/ {print \$2}"` but once the branch was merged into master this was returning the **PR hash and origin/master**.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your branch was merged into master that means every branch created since then contains the commit hash. Otherwise `git branch --remotes --contains <hash>` would be able to help you, but now it probably shows a lot of different branches :/

Comment: @Kim No this command return: origin/master

Comment: As I wrote before the command. You have merged the branch containing the commit into master. That means every branch created from master since then contains the commit... including origin/master itself.

Comment: So this means there is no way that I can get the exact Branch name using the commit hash after I have merged it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "the exact Branch". Are you referring to the branch which the commit originally was created as a part of? In that case no. Branches aren't really anything more than pointers to commits, commits don't store any information about branches.

Comment: @Kim Thank you very much for your explanation, I will use another way instead of the commit hash to achieve what I need